# C segfaults on string operation

Tags: c, string, for-loop, segmentation-fault

I'm writing a little programme to remove a word from a string. C segfaults in the for-loop inside the removeWord function (the third printf is never executed). What can the reason be? I'm an absolute newbee in C. When I try to print str[j] as %s inside the for loop, the compiler complains about str being an integer, not a string. Why is that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void removeWord(char * str, char * toRemove)
{
    int i, j, k, stringLen, toRemoveLen;
    stringLen   = strlen(str);      // Length of string
    toRemoveLen = strlen(toRemove); // Length of word to remove
// ...(code for finding the word)...
        printf ("str='%s' StrLen=%d ToRem=%d i=%d j=%d\n",str, stringLen, toRemoveLen, i, j);
        for(j=i; j<=stringLen - toRemoveLen; j++)
        {
            printf ("j=%d\n", j);
            str[j] = str[j + toRemoveLen];
        }
        printf ("i=%d j=%d\n", i, j);
}

int main(void)
{
    char * term = "from the ";
    removeWord(term, "from");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char * term = "from the ";`-> `char term[] = "from the ";`

Answer (score 0):

It's string literal. You can't modify it. As a result you get a segfault trying to modify it.(Actually it's undefined behavior).

What you can do is

```
char  term[] = "from the ";
```

that will help you modify it, which is what you want.

Even you can take a `char*` and allocate memory in it and copy the string but that's an overkill for this task.

From the standard it can be quoted that **§6.4.5**

> It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
>   elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
>   modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**

In your case `temp` basically holds the address of the string literal which is non-modifiable. If you copy it and then that will be modifiable.